# Combobox dinâmico com jQuery + Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel-eloquent

Estou numa tela de cadastro onde existe um combobox de Estado e Cidades.

Cidade tem q ser preenchida após o estado ser selecionado.

Tenho o create.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('estado', 'Estado:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('estado', $estados) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('cidade', 'Cidade:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('cidade', []) !!}
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('select[name=estado]').change(function () {
        var id_estado = $(this).val();

       // $('select[name=cidade]').html('').append('<option value="">  Carregando...  </option>');
        $.get('/cidades/' + id_estado, function (cidades) {
            $('select[name=cidade]').empty();
            $.each(cidades, function (key, value) {
                $('select[name=cidade]').append('<option value=' + value.id_cidade + '>' + value.nome + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

E o controller:

```
class CidadeController extends Controller
{
    private $estadoModel;

    public function __construct(Estado $estado)
    {
        $this->estadoModel = $estado;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $estados = $this->estadoModel->lists('nome', 'id_estado');

        return view('contas.create', compact('estados'));
    }

    public function getCidades($id_estado)
    {

        $estado = $this->estadoModel->find($id_estado);

        $cidades = $estado->cidades()->getQuery()->get(['id_estado', 'nome']);

        return Response::json($cidades);

    }
```

Porém usando o debugar do laravel está fazendo a consulta errada:

```
select * from `estados` where `estados`.`id_estado` = '3' limit 1

select `id_estado`, `nome` from `cidades` where `cidades`.`id_cidade` = '3' and `cidades`.`id_cidade` is not null
```

Alguém pode me ajudar porque está fazendo a consulta errada?

Comment: Adicione o seu Model de Estados e Cidades por favor, pois acredito que seja um problema no relacionamento, fora isso informe a versão do Laravel que você está utilizando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após comentar a sua pergunta, notei de cara que o seu erro está na definição do relacionamento de Estado com Cidades (hasMany).

A função `hasMany` espera os seguintes parâmetros:

- O model (+namespace)
- A **foreign Key (FK)** presente neste model, ou seja, o campo que faz a conexão de cidade com estado, que neste caso é `id_estado`
- E a **primary key (PK)** do model atual, neste caso, do Estado (não é obrigatório)

Então a maneira correta de fazer esse relacionamento seria:

```
return $this->hasMany('Realito\Cidade','id_estado');
```

---

Alguns pontos para você verificar no seu código:

#### Estado model

Definição do relacionamento com o model Cidade (hasMany - há/tem muitos(as))

```
class Estado extends Model
{

    // outros códigos

    public function cidades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Realito\Cidade', 'id_estado')
    }

    // outros códigos

}
```

#### Cidade model

Definição do relacionamento com o model Estado (belongsTo - pertence a...).

```
class Cidade extends Model
{

    // outros códigos

    public function estado()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Realito\Estado', 'id_estado')
    }

    // outros códigos

}
```

Aconselho sempre a definir o nome do controller no Plural, afinal de contas, é uma convenção do Laravel e de muitos outros frameworks .

```
class CidadesController extends Controller
{
    // outros códigos

    public function getCidades($id_estado)
    {
        $estado = $this->estadoModel->findOrFail($id_estado);
        $cidades = $estado->cidades()->lists('nome', 'id');

        // não entendi porque você está selecionando o campo id_estado 
        // ->get(['id_estado', 'nome']);

        return Response::json($cidades);
    }

    // outros códigos
}
```

O uso do `findOrFail` evita problemas com ids inválidos, mas também isso pode ser tratamento de "n" maneiras diferentes, com um simples if ou até um try catch.

Quanto ao `lists()`, é incrivelmente mais fácil utilizá-lo para retornar um arrary contendo apenas o id e o nome/valor escolhido.

---

No mais, peço que valide o seu código e compare ele com o meu.

Deixe um comentário para que eu possa te auxiliar caso tenha alguma dúvida.

Comment: Muito obrigado Patrick ajudou bastante, iniciando no laravel agora surgi alguns problemas

Comment: @raphael Tranquilo meu amigo, é assim mesmo. Levei uma surra no inicio... agora que peguei o jeito também. Lembre de excluir a sua resposta e adicionar o código dela na sua pergunta (clique em editar sua pergunta).

Answer (score 0):

Estou usando a versão Laravel 5.0

```
    class Estado extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_estado';

    protected $fillable = [

        'nome',
        'regiao',
        'sigla'

    ];

    public $timestamps  = false;

    public function cidades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Realito\Cidade','id_cidade');
    }





class Cidade extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_cidade';

    protected $fillable = ['id_estado','nome'];



    public function estado()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Realito\Estado','id_estado');
    }

}
```

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione os models na pergunta e não como uma resposta. Após isso, exclua sua resposta.